Spring Boot RestApi with Spring Security, JWT 403 error
I am using Spring Boot 3.2 and Spring Security 6.2, and the login and sign-up controllers proceed normally. Even valid tokens are returned, but if you request a post registration controller, an empty 403 error will appear, and if you send a request to a controller that has not been declared, an empty 403 error will appear. My intention is to store the user's nickname contained in jwt as the author by passing it to the dto class. Here's my source code.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtUtils jwtUtils, JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(jwtProvider, jwtUtils), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint));

        return http.build();
    }
}


@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    public JwtUtils(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository, JwtProvider jwtProvider, MemberRepository memberRepository) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
    }

    public String getHeaderToken(HttpServletRequest request, String type) {
        return type.equals("Access")
                ? request.getHeader(jwtProvider.getAccessTokenHeader())
                : request.getHeader(jwtProvider.getRefreshTokenHeader());
    }

    public Boolean tokenValidation(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(jwtProvider.getKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean refreshTokenValidation(String token) {
        if (!tokenValidation(token)) return false;

        Optional<RefreshToken> refreshToken = refreshTokenRepository.findByMemberEmail(getEmailFromToken(token));
        return refreshToken.isPresent() && token.equals(refreshToken.get().getRefreshToken());
    }

    public Authentication createAuthentication(String email) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getEmailFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(jwtProvider.getKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String getNicknameFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(jwtProvider.getKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().get("nickname", String.class);
    }

    public Member loadMemberByEmail(String email) {
        return memberRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found: " + email));
    }
}

@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    public JwtUtils(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository, JwtProvider jwtProvider, MemberRepository memberRepository) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
    }

    public String getHeaderToken(HttpServletRequest request, String type) {
        return type.equals("Access")
                ? request.getHeader(jwtProvider.getAccessTokenHeader())
                : request.getHeader(jwtProvider.getRefreshTokenHeader());
    }

    public Boolean tokenValidation(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(jwtProvider.getKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean refreshTokenValidation(String token) {
        if (!tokenValidation(token)) return false;

        Optional<RefreshToken> refreshToken = refreshTokenRepository.findByMemberEmail(getEmailFromToken(token));
        return refreshToken.isPresent() && token.equals(refreshToken.get().getRefreshToken());
    }

    public Authentication createAuthentication(String email) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getEmailFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(jwtProvider.getKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String getNicknameFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(jwtProvider.getKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().get("nickname", String.class);
    }

    public Member loadMemberByEmail(String email) {
        return memberRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found: " + email));
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class BoardServiceImpl implements BoardService {

    private final BoardRepository boardRepository;

    public BoardServiceImpl(BoardRepository boardRepository) {
        this.boardRepository = boardRepository;
    }

    public void createBoard(BoardCreateRequestDto requestDto, String nickname) {

        Board board = Board.builder()
                .title(requestDto.getTitle())
                .content(requestDto.getContent())
                .category(requestDto.getCategory())
                .writer(nickname)
                .build();

        boardRepository.save(board);
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BoardCreateRequestDto {

    private String title;

    private String content;

    private Category category;

    @Builder
    public BoardCreateRequestDto(String title, String content, Category category) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.category = category;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/board")
public class BoardController {

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private final BoardService boardService;

    public BoardController(JwtUtils jwtUtils, BoardService boardService) {
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.boardService = boardService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createBoard(@RequestBody BoardCreateRequestDto requestDto, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = jwtUtils.getHeaderToken(request, "Access");

        if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
            String nickname = jwtUtils.getNicknameFromToken(token);

            boardService.createBoard(requestDto, nickname);

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Board created");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}

@Log4j2
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    public JwtFilter(JwtProvider jwtProvider, JwtUtils jwtUtils) {
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String accessToken = jwtUtils.getHeaderToken(request, "Access");
        String refreshToken = jwtUtils.getHeaderToken(request, "Refresh");

        log.debug(accessToken);
        log.debug(refreshToken);

        try {
            if (accessToken != null) {
                if (jwtUtils.tokenValidation(accessToken)) {
                    setAuthentication(jwtUtils.getEmailFromToken(accessToken));
                    log.debug("Access token valid. Authentication set.");
                } else if (refreshToken != null && jwtUtils.refreshTokenValidation(refreshToken)) {
                    refreshAccessToken(refreshToken, response);
                    log.debug("Refresh token valid. Access token refreshed");
                } else {
                    log.debug("Access token invalid. Sending error response.");
                    jwtExceptionHandler(response, "Access Token Expired or Invalid", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (refreshToken != null && jwtUtils.refreshTokenValidation(refreshToken)) {
                refreshAccessToken(refreshToken, response);
                log.debug("Refresh token valid. Access token refreshed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error during JWT validation: ", e);
            jwtExceptionHandler(response, "Internal Server Error", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void refreshAccessToken(String refreshToken, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String email = jwtUtils.getEmailFromToken(refreshToken);
        Member member = jwtUtils.loadMemberByEmail(email);
        String newAccessToken = jwtProvider.createToken(
                new TokenPayload(email, member.getRole().name(), member.getNickname()), "Access"
        );
        jwtProvider.setHeaderAccessToken(response, newAccessToken);
        setAuthentication(email);
    }

    private void setAuthentication(String email) {
        Authentication authentication = jwtUtils.createAuthentication(email);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    private void jwtExceptionHandler(HttpServletResponse response, String msg, HttpStatus status) {
        response.setStatus(status.value());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try {
            String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonMap("error", msg));
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

I tried setting crsf and tried everything I could, but it didn't work.

would be good to see your JwtFilter class. Also your user should/will end up in the  security context and you can look it up wherever with SecurityContextHolder

I add JwtFilter class code. Thank you to check my post.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Code looks reasonable, if a little convoluted- The key thing is to check that SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); is properly invoked,
For peace of mind you can also check whether authentication.isAuthenticated() is true, which it should be, based on your code.

Would have left that as a comment but I went over the character limit-
Code looks reasonable, if a little convoluted- The key thing is to check that SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication) is properly invoked, which it seems to be.
For peace of mind you can also check whether authentication.isAuthenticated() is true, which it should be, based on your code.
you can try logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE in your application.properties - that could give you some insights- Maybe a filter down the filter chain is messing with the authentication.
As an experiment you can try to add your filter after the LogoutFilter instead of before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, eg
  .addFilterAfter(new JwtFilter(jwtProvider, jwtUtils), LogoutFilter.class)

